# PostgreSQL SELECT COUNT returning a bunch of 1s

Tags: postgresql

The following is my code that returns the correct number of rows of nameids that I am looking for (75). Then, when I do COUNT(DISTINCT nameid) at the top instead, it just returns 145 1s instead of the number of rows in my query (75). It just says

```
1
1
1
..
1
(145 rows)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT nameid
FROM
    shop
WHERE
    yearid >= 2000
GROUP BY
    nameid,
    yearid
HAVING
    SUM(spend) > 98;
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of your table?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same column in group by and in aggregated  function  in this way you obtain only 1  ( the distinct count of a value grouped  bybthe same value is 1)
if you want count the DISTINCT nameid for each year  with sum(spend) > 68 you should use

```
    SELECT yearid, COUNT(DISTINCT nameid)
    FROM     shop
    WHERE
        yearid >= 2000
    GROUP BY   yearid
    HAVING  SUM(spend) > 98;
```